# Datetime no leading zero

Tags: python, datetime, time, strftime

Tried several things but doesn't seem to work

```
time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
time.strftime("%H:%M")
await 
client.get_channel(timechannel).edit(name=f"{time.hour}:{time.minute} UTC")
```

Comment: Is your problem that the hour and minute have no leading zero or do you want that?

Comment: please add details to your question. what do you mean by "Datetime no leading zero"?

Comment: sorry for the undetailed info. I'm currently having an issue with the result. it shows 16:4 instead of 16:04 and 0:8 instead of 00:08

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
await client.get_channel(timechannel).edit(name=time.strftime('%H:%M UTC'))
```

Comment: `name=time.strftime('%H:%M UTC')` looks shorter.

Comment: @bereal that code doesn't work for me I'm connecting my code to a bot into a discord channel.

Comment: `await client.get_channel(timechannel).edit name=time.strftime('%H:%M UTC')
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: @SimonGoedhart parentheses?

Comment: I know I did but you said it would be shorter with this code

Comment: @SimonGoedhart I meant the formatting approach, which luigigi already added to the post.

Comment: @bereal owh sorry just started with coding and stack overflow don't mind me